# Command Center Events, Only responding to Wireless headphones Play/Pause

Tags: swift, swift3, avplayer, avaudioplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I am using AVplayer to stream audio from url. The audio is playing, I set up remote command events. I am only using the Play/Pause buttons, they're working on the lock screen. The issue is that whenever I connect wired headphones, the play/pause buttons on the headphones doesn't work. They worked for wireless headphones. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated...

**Audio Session**

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

        try audioSession.setActive(true)

    } catch {

        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
```

**Command Center**

```
func setupRemoteTransportControls() {

    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
 commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true

    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(handler: { (event) in    // Begin playing the current track
        if self.audioPlayer.rate == 0.0 {
            self.audioPlayer.play()
            //return .success
        }
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
   })

    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(handler: { (event) in    // Pause current track
        if self.audioPlayer.rate == 1.0 {
            self.audioPlayer.pause()
        }
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
     })
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix my issue by using **togglePlayPauseCommand**, this is used for wired headphones touch events.